# ParseObject queries with relative search parameters

Tags: c#, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm rather new to Parse and Cloud Code, and I'm having trouble writing a certain query script.

I have a table of Salespeople, who have two integers : dailySold and dailyQuota.

The dailySold is reset to 0 each day, and the dailyQuota is defined by upper management.

Now, I'd like to make queries that call out bulks of users. Say, all users which dailySold is below their dailyQuota. In MySQL it would just look like this :

```
select * from salespeople where dailySold < dailyQuota
```

But in Parse / CloudCode I have been unable to find something like this. Currently, I'm loading all the entries, and going through them one by one, populating a large array clientside. This feels like the absolutely wrong way of doing it.

And the query.WhereNotEqualTo() function (and their siblings) seem to only be able to compare with static queries.

Does anyone know how to put together a query to optimize this ? I need it to go through thousands of records, and its often only 10-20 results I'm interested in. If nothing else, I'll have to make a cloudcode function that iterates for me serverside, but I still feel like there is some function I should be able to use, to make a more lean query.

Comment: dailyQuota is not the same for all? It varies from salesperson to salesperson?

Comment: yes, the quota is changing. Not that they are unique, but the quota is calced based on last weeks sales + some other factors. Sounds like the fastest thing to do is group them and run them in clusters...

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two columns in a query. You can only compare a key with a provided object. If the `dailyQuota` is set by upper management, I'm assuming this is the same for all salespeople, or for groups of people. I'd suggest first making a query for the daily quota and then either use

```
whereKey:matchesKey:inQuery
```

or just fetch the `dailyQuota` first and then use that value in the second query.